# Fastlane selecting wrong provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, fastlane

I've configured my iOS project with 2 targets and several configurations (6 for the 1st target, debug and release for the 2nd target).

Each of the release configurations has different bundleID, hence the appropriate adhoc distribution provisioning profiles are selected (in the gym command):

```
desc "Build target1-config1"
  lane :deployTarget1 do
    gym(
      workspace: "myProj-ios.xcworkspace",
      scheme: "target1-config1",
      configuration: "target1-Release",
      export_method: "ad-hoc",
      export_options: {
        provisioningProfiles: {  
          "com.target1.config1" => "AdHocProvProfile1"
        }
      },
      output_directory: "./build",
      output_name: "target1-config1.ipa"
      )
    firebase_app_distribution(
      app: "xxxxxxxx",
      groups: "ios_app_testers",
      release_notes: "Automatic dev build from develop",
      firebase_cli_path: "/usr/local/bin/firebase",
      debug: true
      )
  end
```

When trying to build target2 with AdhocProvProfile2, I receive an error. It looks like fastlane is not properly selecting the provProfile (and bundleID!). Additionally, in project settings the profiles are selected properly. What could be causing the issue? There is no external gym file.

```
 There seems to be a mismatch between your provided `export_method` in gym
[11:15:55]: and the selected provisioning profiles. You passed the following options:
[11:15:55]:   export_method:      ad-hoc
[11:15:55]:   Bundle identifier:  com.target1.config1
[11:15:55]:   Profile name:       Target1 Development ProvProfile
[11:15:55]:   Profile type:       development
```